# Sum one column in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling with this...
This is for generating an order invoice, I would like to sum price for every product the client ordered.

The **products** array contains 5 columns :

1. product name
2. product category
3. quantity (always equal to one here)
4. product price (unit)
5. product price * quantity

I would like to sum the 4th column *(product price, unit)*

How am I able to do this ? Thanks a lot

```
// GET ALL ORDERED PRODUCTS

$rq = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM transactions_details WHERE transaction_name = ?');
$rq->execute([$invoice_id]);
$result = $rq->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $items) {

  // Get product name from id
  $rqProductInfo = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ? ORDER BY name ASC');
  $rqProductInfo->execute([$items->product_id]);
  $productInfo = $rqProductInfo->fetch();

  // Get category name from cat
  $rqProductCat = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?');
  $rqProductCat->execute([$productInfo->cat]);
  $productCat = $rqProductCat->fetch();
  // --------------
  $products = [
    ["$productInfo->name", 'catégorie « '.$productCat->name.' »', 1, "$productInfo->price €", "$productInfo->price €"]
  ];
  var_dump($products);
  foreach ($products as $i) { $invoice->add("items", $i); }
}
```

Comment: You could probably do all of this with `join`s. Can you add more details about the table structure and relationships?

Comment: Oh i see where you tells me to go !
Table transactions_products contains (id -autoincrement-, transaction_name, product_id, product_price). So maybe i will just have to sum product_price column. But is there anyway to do it with the foreach loop ? Thanks

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql